# Get total count of collection after setting limit and offset using mongodb, mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen several questions on this topic on Google but I am not sure why any of them is working for me.

I am simply trying to query a data from collection with limit and offset passing which seems working fine but I need one more parameter where it returns the total no. of data available in that collection.

Is it that hard ? I have spend over 12 hours just for this. Must be I am a beginner in Nodejs and mongodb.

With my research I found that `db.collection(collection_name).count())`
[image: blank returns]

should return total count. But it shows blank object where it is placed. I again came to know that it is being depreciated and now we should use `Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount` . Again check the [documents of mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/). As per the document it says: `db.orders.countDocuments({})` where I replaced the orders with my collection name which becomes. `db.allMinisters.countDocuments({})`

I get this error `{"error":{"message":"Cannot read property 'countDocuments' of undefined"}}`. I even use `db.collection('allMinisters').countDocuments({})` but it return promise and display blank object as count.

My code:-

```
    mongoose.connect( url, (err, database) => { 
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        db = database;

    });

    exports.getAllMinisters = (req, res, next)=>{
        console.log(db.collection('allMinisters').countDocuments({}));
        db.collection('allMinisters').find({}).skip(0).limit(10).toArray(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {return next(err);}
              const response = {
                  count: db.collection('allMinisters').count(),
                  allMinisters: docs.map(docs=>docs),
                  status: 'success'
              }
  
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
          });
      };
```

How do I get total count ?

Comment: use ```asyn/await``` or ```callback``` eg. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your REST API looks like but try something like this

```
exports.getallMinisters = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.params.docs) {
    const allMinisters = await allMinister.find({ docs: req.params.docs });

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      count: allMinisters.length,
      data: allMinisters
    });
  } else {
    //errorResponse;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fixed this by simply creating async based function and await the total count query.

```
exports.getAllMinisters = async (req, res, next)=>{
        totalCount  = await db.collection('allMinisters').countDocuments({});
        db.collection('allMinisters').find({}).skip(0).limit(10).toArray(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {return next(err);}
              const response = {
                  count: totalCount,
                  allMinisters: docs.map(docs=>docs),
                  status: 'success'
              }
  
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
          });
      };
```